*Intrinsic* proof that the Lie algebra of $\text{GL}_n$ is $M_n$
The usual proof I've seen that the Lie algebra of $\text{GL}_n$ is the space $M_n$ of all $n \times n$ matrices goes as follows: $\text{GL}_n$ can be embedded as an open subset of $M_n$, which is a vector space, so $T_I \text{GL}_n \simeq T_I M_n \simeq M_n$. Then you can do a computation in coordinates to show that the differential Lie bracket coincides with the regular matrix commutator.
This is straightforward enough, but a bit unsatisfying for such a fundamental result. What I'd really like is to have, for any finite dimensional vector space $V$, some natural, intrinsic identification of $\text{End}(V)$ with the left-invariant vector fields on $\text{Aut}(V)$. Does such a thing exist, or is the proof outlined above the only one?

The identification (as vector spaces) of $\mathrm{End}(V)$ with $T_{I}\mathrm{Aut}(V)$ follows in the same way, and no coordinates are needed. What you are interested in is determining the bracket without coordinates, right?

We first describe a coordinate free isomorphism between $T_{I}\mathsf{Aut}(V)$ and $\mathsf{End}(V)$. Since $\mathsf{Aut}(V)$ is open in $\mathsf{End}(V)$, they both have the same tangent space at the identity, and since $\mathsf{End}(V)$ is a vector space, we have
$$T_{I}\mathsf{Aut}(V)\cong T_{I}\mathsf{End(V)}\cong\mathsf{End}(V)$$
where the last isomorphism takes $\phi\in\mathsf{End}(V)$ to the tangent vector
$$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg\vert_{t=0}(I+t\phi)\in T_{I}\mathsf{Aut}(V).$$
Now we want to check that the Lie bracket on $\mathsf{End}(V)$, when viewed as the Lie algebra of the automorphism group, is equal to the commutator.
Let $\phi$ and $\psi$ be arbitrary endomorphisms and consider the left invariant vector fields $X$, $Y\in\mathfrak{X}(\mathsf{Aut}(V))$ such that $X_{I}$ and $Y_{I}$ are (identified with) $\phi$ and $\psi$ respectively.
Now, there is a formula to compute Lie brackets from flows:
$$[X,Y]_{I}=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg\vert_{t=0}(X^{-t})_{*X^{t}(I)}Y_{X^{t}(I)},$$
where $X^{t}\colon\mathsf{Aut}(V)\to\mathsf{Aut}(V)$ is the flow of $X$ at time $t$.
Actually $X^{t}(g)=ge^{t\phi}$ for all $g$ (this follows from the general theory of Lie groups, but you can also check directly that this map satisfies the ODE determined by $X$) and $Y_{X^{t}(I)}=(L_{X^{t}(I)})_{*I}(Y_{I})=X^{t}(I)\psi=e^{t\phi}\psi$ because left multiplication is a linear map.
We get
$$(X^{-t}(I))_{*X^{t}(I)}Y_{X^{t}(I)}=(X^{-t}(I))_{*X^{t}(I)}e^{t\phi}\psi=e^{t\phi}\psi e^{-t\phi},$$
and if we differentiate at zero, we arrive at
$$[X,Y]_{I}=\phi\psi-\psi\phi.$$
Hope this helps!

The theory of linear differential equations gives you such an isomorphism, (and works as well for Banach spaces). if $A$ is a continuos operator of some Banach space $E$, the solution of the differential equation $L\in End(E), {dL \over dt}=A.L$ with initial data $L(0)=Id$ is $exp tA$. But $L$  also defines a vector field on $E$, by the formula $L_x=Lx$, hence on the open set $Aut(E)$. Note that this field is right invariant on $Aut(E)$. if your prefer left invariant consider the differential equation ${dL \over dt}=L.A$
